# how to feed Tensorflow dataset pipeline with an example of triple tensors

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

As it is described in [official Tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets), we can feed a dataset pipeline with examples of pair tensor (input, label). I need to know how can I add one more item like ( input, lable1, lable2)?

Comment: you can just store in the label array, both of the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple!

You just make your dataset method output dictionary instead.

This code is from the link you posted, all the way down to the bottom.

```
def dataset_input_fn():
  filenames = ["/var/data/file1.tfrecord", "/var/data/file2.tfrecord"]
  dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)

  # Use `tf.parse_single_example()` to extract data from a `tf.Example`
  # protocol buffer, and perform any additional per-record preprocessing.
  def parser(record):
    keys_to_features = {
        "image_data": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
        "date_time": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=""),
        "label": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64,
                                    default_value=tf.zeros([], dtype=tf.int64)),
    }
    parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record, keys_to_features)

    # Perform additional preprocessing on the parsed data.
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(parsed["image_data"])
    image = tf.reshape(image, [299, 299, 1])
    label = tf.cast(parsed["label"], tf.int32)

    return {"image_data": image, "date_time": parsed["date_time"]}, label

  # Use `Dataset.map()` to build a pair of a feature dictionary and a label
  # tensor for each example.
  dataset = dataset.map(parser)
  dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
  dataset = dataset.batch(32)
  dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
  iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

  # `features` is a dictionary in which each value is a batch of values for
  # that feature; `labels` is a batch of labels.
  features, labels = iterator.get_next()
  return features, labels
```

Now, `features` is actually a dictionary with the fields `image_data` and `date_time`.
This way, you can add as much as you want to either features or labels, while still sticking to the two outputs.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed the second label should be feed as a feature.